# Mapping state of children to Parent array state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

**Description:** 
My parent Component A has a state array such as:

`state = { validatedSteps = [false, false, false] }`

The state of A has for array length the exact same number of children, therefore, in this case, 3.

Each children have a state such as:

`state = { validated = true }`

**Question:** What is the best way for me to map the parent state array to reflect the state of each children?

Comment: One way is using ```callback function```. You can define a function in the parent and send it to the child using ```props```, then in the child if the state has changed, calling that callback function.

Comment: @salman.zare agreed, however how could I be sure which position of the array should be updated?

Comment: For the callback function you would also need to include the `index` to ensure you're updating the correct item in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In each child component, when you change the state, you can notify the parent component and update the state of appropriate step. For example, I am assuming three components as , `Step1`, `Step2`, `Step3`.

In Parent component,

```
validateStep(step) {
  let stepsValidated = this.state.validatedSteps.slice();
  stepsValidated[step]=true
  this.setState({
    validatedSteps: stepsValidated
  })
}

<Step1 validate={this.validateStep}/>
<Step2 validate={this.validateStep}/>
<Step3 validate={this.validateStep}/>
```

In Child components, lets take `Step1`, you can pass the appropriate index as the parameter, something like this.

```
...
validate() {
  this.stateState({ validated:true }, 
  ()=> {
    this.props.validate(0);
  })
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If we change the  `stepsValidated[step]=true`   to the   `stepsValidated[step-1]=true`
 , will be completely correct.

Comment: I added the above response as the right one as this only completes the actual answer even though I understand that you did mean that on first comment you made.